# how can I fill the blank space in the example below?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have to fill the blank space with the same description that appears below that belong to the  same STTCKT. My table is a temporary table.
[image: sample]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your blank line is actually an empty string, you can join the table to itself and use the string value for the same key.

```
UPDATE  tt
SET     [stbk#] = tt2.[stbk#]
FROM    dbo.TestTable tt
JOIN    dbo.TestTable tt2
        ON tt.sttkt = tt2.sttkt
           AND NULLIF(tt2.[stbk#], '') IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: who is dbo.TestTable? my database name is #TempB

Comment: I didn't have your table name, so I create a table called dbo.TestTable with two columns: `CREATE TABLE dbo.TestTable ([stbk#] VARCHAR(10), sttkt INT)`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update yourtable 
set stbk# = x.stbk#
from (
select sttckt, stbk# 
where len(ltrim(rtrim(stbk3)))>0) x
where len(ltrim(rtrim(yourtable.stbk3)))=0
and yourtable.sttkt = x.sttkt
```

Comment: I got this error Invalid column name 'stbk#' and when I double clic on the error, sql highlighted this where len(ltrim(rtrim(stbk#)))>0) x

Comment: # is probably a reserved character.  If you enclose the field name in brackets[] it should work.